# How do I add multiple emails to an "imaplib" search criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

I'm trying to search emails from more than one email address, currently I can search for one email address using following code:

```
typ, data = mail.search(None, '(FROM "myname@gmail.com" UNSEEN)')
```

How do I add another `email, ids` or series of `email, ids` to this search criteria?

**INFO:** I'm working on a Windows machine and using python version 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gmail, you can use the 'X-GM-RAW' extension to search using normal [Gmail search functionalit](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)y i.e:
typ, data = mail.uid('search', None,  'X-GM-RAW', 'from:email1@email OR from:email2@email')